# Append XMLstring to XML file periodically

Tags: c#, xml, append, xmldocument

I have a string variable 'str'. It holds an XML data in string format and updates periodically in real time. I want to save it in an XML file called "HL7.xml" and append it then onwards. 
This is my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(str);
doc.Save("HL7.xml");
```

Please help me append it everytime. 
**Note: Append it everytime, not delete old data and overwrite**

Answer (score 0):

[File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.AppendAllText("HL7.xml", doc.ToString());
```

Comment: It writes the string to the xml document as simple text. doc.save("filename") used to save the string as xml format. So your code does not give the required result.

Comment: @SayanSen, xml representation in file is string. Do you mean tabs onlys? If so, you can write `doc.Tostring()`

Comment: Xml specification says you should have only one element at the root level.   Appending data to a file will give more than one element at root level.  This is referred to as "NOT Well-Formed" Xml. It is allowable but many methods for reading the file will give an error.  If you need to read file in c# use the XmlReader with the option "Fragmented".  You are using HL7 which is medical records and if you need any help let me know.  I've been working with HL7 for a number of years.